# Selenium 2 and c#: How to get html-code below a specific IWebElement?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How is it possible to get the html code below a specific IWebElement using Selenium 2 and C#?

Or, is this not possible at this time and I need to fetch the whole html sourcecode via `IWebDriver.PageSource`?

Comment: Did you consider HTMl parsing for it?   http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium

Comment: But when using html parsing, I need to fetch the data via IWebDriver.PageSource before I can parse it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry misread your question. There is indeed one API for this and as you said -

IWebDriver.PageSource

On a different note, did you support Selenium Proposal on area51 - 
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium
You just need to click Commit button to support site, while having logged in using your stack ovewflow account. This proposal is backed by SeleniumHQ and we need more users to commit to it to make it see day of light.